# Weird font handling in Google Chrome

Tags: debian, chrome, fonts

Running on Debian 10. Problem occurs on several websites and only via Google Chrome. I've found two so far: Github and Codeforces. Tried to purge Chrome and installing it from scratch, but that didn't help. I'm not sure which info I should provide here as I'm quite new to Linux.\

[Example #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9lvp.jpg)
[Example #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WNHb.jpg)
['Tweaks' settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqRng.jpg)
[System setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEOwg.jpg)\

**UPD1**: When logging in as another user, the fonts are fine on both websites.

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: @Dave Should look like this instead: https://i.imgur.com/FBDwAEM.png
I guess the actual problem is that Chrome loads incorrect font

Answer (score 0):

Removing `./local/share/fonts` folder fixed the problem.